# Service Documents failed while accessing document with id xxxx

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

This script is for creating name badges from a list of names on a spreadsheet. Its takes rows of data from a Google spreadsheet and writes them to a Google Document in a formatted way. When I ran it a week ago, it worked fine with no errors.

Today I started getting the following error every time I ran the script:

> Service Documents failed while accessing document with id
> 19Ujy457kSUyQs03O2Xp6zBmulzcxHkb17Bi7w0xMCDI.

The id in the error refers to the the document where I'm trying to write the values.

Here is my Google Apps Script code:

```
function createBadges() {
 //Ids for docs and sheets 
  var docTemplateId = "1VYuyFS_t5ha-7fDLhhWHOFxgeELr7QOF23sMLTnzy9E"; 
  var docFinalId = "19Ujy457kSUyQs03O2Xp6zBmulzcxHkb17Bi7w0xMCDI";
  // var docFinalId = DocumentApp.create('23-24 FamU Makeup Badges').getId();
  var ssID = "1X9aAe5M5uQyYQ0JzYL2ZWi31NPQUdG93TDw_XbpHNWI"; 
  
  //Get the docs and sheet 
  var docTemplate = DocumentApp.openById(docTemplateId); 
  var docFinal = DocumentApp.openById(docFinalId);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(sheet)
  var data =  sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1,10).getValues();

  var templateParagraphs = docTemplate.getBody().getParagraphs();

  docFinal.getBody().clear()

  var batchSize = 6;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += batchSize) {
      var rowsToProcess = data.slice(i, i + batchSize);
      createPageWithBadges(rowsToProcess, templateParagraphs, docFinal);
    }

  const body = docFinal.getBody();
  body.setMarginLeft(42)
  body.setMarginRight(30)
  body.setMarginTop(30)
  body.setMarginBottom(6)

}


function createPageWithBadges(rows, templateParagraphs, docFinal) {
  if (docFinal.getBody().getText() !== "") {
    docFinal.getBody().appendPageBreak();
  }

  // Create a table with two rows and two columns
  var table = docFinal.getBody().appendTable([
    ["", ""], // First row with two cells
    ["", ""],  // Second row with two cells
    ["", ""]
  ]);

  table.setColumnWidth(0, 260); // Adjust the column width as needed
  table.setColumnWidth(1, 240); // Adjust the column width as needed
  table.setBorderWidth(0)

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    var cell = table.getCell(Math.floor(i / 2), i % 2);
    var copiedParagraphs = templateParagraphs.map(function (p) {
      return p.copy()
        .replaceText("{lastName}", row[0])
        .replaceText("{firstName}", row[1])
        .replaceText("{famNumber}", row[2])
        .replaceText("{gradeLevel}", row[3]==='Parent'?`Parent` :`Grade ${row[3]}`)
        .replaceText("{first}", row[6])
         .replaceText("{class1}",row[8])
         .replaceText("{class2}",row[9])
        .replaceText("{second}", row[7]);
    });

    copiedParagraphs.forEach(function (copiedParagraph) {
      cell.appendParagraph(copiedParagraph);
    });
  }


  }
```

This code combines 6 rows of data from the Spreadsheet onto one page of the Google Document.

I know there are similar issues already on Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions appear to apply to this example. As far as I know, this document has no footers, the google sheet tab is retrieved correctly, the spreadsheet is already saved as a Google Sheet (not an excel file),and I have adequate permissions to run this script.

What could be causing this script to malfunction when it worked fine just a week ago? Could it be an issue of runtime quotas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I ran this script with a different google account with an all template, target document, and spreadsheet. The script worked as expected. This makes me think it IS a matter of runtime quotas.

Comment: This looks like a server-side transient error. It doesn't look like your script ran into any of Apps Script's quotas listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). Which line is throwing the error and has this been going on for mroe than 24 hours? Do you also have any active add-ons in Google Docs?

Comment: I'm not aware of using any active add-ons.

I just ran the script again and it worked without any errors. I'm both thrilled and even more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible explanation:

Considering that running the script again produced no errors, it's likely that none of Apps Script's documented [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) are the culprit. However, Apps Script does have limits that aren't published and that may change without notice. If you can reliably get the same error after running the script a certain number of times, there's a high likelihood that you're hittin at least one of those undocumented limits.

Lastly, there's an existing [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/305838577) regarding the error that you're getting. In case you encounter the same error again, do click the `+1` icon on the upper right of the issue tracker page to let Google know that you're affected as well.

Comment: Thank you for your insight on this. I shared the script with another google account, ran the script and it worked fine. Tried it again with the original google account and then it worked. I might go ahead and check out the bug you mentioned. Thank you!